# How can I get the name of the team instead of its ID

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

**teams**

- TeamID as PK, int
- TeamName

**matches** (bridge table)

- MatchID as PK, int
- TeamID_1 as PK, FK, int
- TeamID_2 as PK, FK, int
- MatchWinner

How could I manage to get `TeamName` instead of `TeamID` in the final table?
Already tried using, inner and outer joins etc.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(m.MatchID, m.TeamID_1, m.TeamID_2) AS MatchID, m.TeamID_1 AS 'Team 1', m.TeamID_2 AS 'Team 2', m.MatchWinner AS 'Winner'
    FROM teams t
    JOIN matches m
    ON t.TeamID IN (m.TeamID_1, m.TeamID_2)
    WHERE t.TeamName = 'Fnatic';
```

[image: issue]

The final table should look like

**MatchID - Team 1 - Team 2 - Winner**
18582 - Fnatic - Astralis - Fnatic

Comment: Please paste the query into the question.....

Comment: @e2-e4 now you can find it there

Comment: Please [edit] your question so the title matches the question.

Comment: @O. Jones Hopefully, it's better now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join `matches` with 2 copies of `teams`:

```
select m.matchid, t1.teamname team1, t2.teamname team2, m.Winner
from matches m 
inner join teams t1 on t1.teamid = m.teamid_1 
inner join teams t2 on t2.teamid = m.teamid_2
where 'Fnatic' in (t1.teamname, t2.teamname)
```